# Animating a border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar, which has a gradient bottom border. I want to animate that gradient so the colors move. I tried using the animation provided on this site http://www.gradient-animator.com/ , but couldn't get it to work. Could you point me out to a solution? I don't mind using CSS only, or some combination of javascript with it.

Would it be possible to create a border-image gradient transition this way? https://jsfiddle.net/q4x5zyty/

I am trying to animate the **gradient color border**.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  color: #e0dcd4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.top-nav-container {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 60px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #C04848, #480048) 100% 1;
  border-image-slice: 50;
  border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
  box-shadow: black 0px 12px 9px -9px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #0b131b;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 0%, circle farthest-side, #1b232c 8%, #10171d);
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at 50% 0%, #1b232c 8%, #10171d);
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.nav-buttons {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-buttons-each {
  width: 25%;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: #e0dcd4;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.top-navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="w-container top-nav-container">
      <div class="w-nav top-navbar" data-collapse="tiny" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" data-contain="1">
        <div class="w-container">
          <nav class="w-nav-menu nav-buttons" role="navigation">
          </nav>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not seeing any attempt at animating in the code provided. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=animate+gradient+css

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"couldn't get it to work"_? That gradient editor provides all the code you need, so you shouldn't need to _"do"_ anything to get it to work. It should just work. For example, I copied and pasted the exact code they provided, and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/n5ss3dtu/

Comment: @ChristianVarga I am trying to animate the border color, not the background color. I may have pasted it wrongly, but I couldn't get it to do the same thing for the border color, not the bg color.

Comment: @Paulie_D I am trying to animate the border gradient, that's why I haven't been able to get it to work. Unfortunately I had been working ont his a few hours ago before having to do some real work, and don't have the code for my tries. They were mostly copy-pastes of provided code trying to edit it so it animated the border color, but I still couldn't get it to animate.

Comment: @Gerardo We got you want to animate border, but what is your approach or how do you want it to animate.

Comment: @divy3993 My first try was pasting the code from http://www.gradient-animator.com/, changing background to border-image, but I can't find which property of border-image could be used to move the gradient over. I think that if I knew that, I could create the animation to move the gradient left and right. It would be the equivalent of background position to border-image. Or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp) is a list of properties that are "animatable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what http://www.gradient-animator.com/ is doing is animating the position of the background so that it appears that the color of the background is being animated. 
in order to achieve the same effect, you will have to "fake" the border by nesting elements. here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eqnvogz/).

### The html:

```
<div>
    <div> HELLO </div>
</div>
```

### The css:

(the padding of the outer element is effectively the `border-width` of its child)

```
div{

    background: linear-gradient(85deg, #246655, #d0e8e2, #ae59bb);
    background-size: 600% 600%;
     padding:20px;
    -webkit-animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;
    animation: AnimationName 5s ease infinite;

}
div > div{
    height:400px;
    background:#fff;


}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:18% 0%}
    50%{background-position:83% 100%}
    100%{background-position:18% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:18% 0%}
    50%{background-position:83% 100%}
    100%{background-position:18% 0%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
    0%{background-position:18% 0%}
    50%{background-position:83% 100%}
    100%{background-position:18% 0%}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking time to answer, finally got around. This is it applied to my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/q4x5zyty/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gradient Animation</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<style>
.head {
background: linear-gradient(270deg, #cc0000, #0028cc, #ccc800);
background-size: 600% 600%;
-webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
}
.head-mid {
background: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 280px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
0%{background-position:0% 50%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
0%{background-position:0% 50%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
0%{background-position:0% 50%}
50%{background-position:100% 50%}
100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="head">
<div class="head-mid"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

try this :)